# Finding one document of every similar documents group

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index with many documents. Every group of these documents contain similar content but not exactly the same. What is the query that would return only one document of every similar documents group?

Comment: what would a 'group' be in this context? Solr has Fieldcollapsing / result grouping: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing. ES has planned this feature for a long time but isn't there yet: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256. That said, not sure if you mean this with 'grouping' at all

Comment: What is a group? Documents with a common field Value?